# How to silence spam or unwanted email from email-lists with Procmail?

Tags: email, procmail

I joined an email-list. I found it low-quality and I don't have time to follow their discussions. Then I informed the head to remove my email but they haven't done it. How can I can silence their emails with Procmail? It is some sort of email-list `Envelope-to:personal@something.com`. They send it from `tiedotus@edistyspuolue.fi`. How can I silence them, i.e. not to get their emails to fill my mailbox, not to bother me with their emails?

```
:0:
* ^FROM:.*@edistyspuolue.fi
* ^TO:personal@something.com
/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

To put all the messages in a dedicated folder, you can use this recipe:

```
:0:
* ^(From|Cc|To).*edistyspuolue.fi
tiedotus
```

Or you could compress it:

```
:0:
* ^(From|Cc|To).*edistyspuolue.fi
| gzip >> junk-tiedotus.gz
```

Or you can just trash it:

```
:0:
* ^(From|Cc|To).*edistyspuolue.fi
/dev/null
```

Comment: `":0:
* ^(From|Cc|To).*edistyspuolue.fi
OR
* ^(To)tiedotus@myEmail.com
tiedotus"` is this possible? To filter out `*.fi` or `.*myEmail.com`?

Comment: @hhh your follow-up question doesn't make any sense, maybe post a new separate question with more details instead?